# how to reload listview from adapter + array

Tags: android, web-services

I am making an android application in which i had used php webservices in which i want to delete a data and after deletion the value is not refreshing, I just tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but still cant get result 
here is  my code please tell me where i m wrong.

```
    Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Identifier_fev = null;
            String Default_Option = null;
            String Quantity1 = null;
            jffDatabase.open();
            Cursor identifie = jffDatabase.getALL();
            if (identifie.moveToPosition(position)) {
                Identifier_fev = identifie.getString(identifie.getColumnIndexOrThrow("identifier"));
               Default_Option = identifie.getString(identifie.getColumnIndexOrThrow("default_option"));
            }

             jffDatabase.delete(Identifier_fev, Default_Option);
            identifier.remove(position);
            title.remove(position);
           defaultPrice.remove(position);
            default_option.remove(position);
            price.remove(position);
            quantity.remove(position);


                Cursor c1 = jffDatabase.getALL();
                if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Quantity1 = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quantity"));
                        update_quantity.add(Quantity1);

                    } while (c1.moveToNext());
                }
                    for (int i = 0; i < update_quantity.size(); i++) {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "" + update_quantity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                      Quantitylbl.setText(update_quantity.get(i).toString());


                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "set " + Quantitylbl.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


            Quantity();
          AddtoCartActivity.Cartcount.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

        }

    });
```